# How to generate a .ipa file from Expo build and sideload on to real device?

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile, expo, ipa

I'm developing a mobile app for my final year project in university using `React Native` and `Expo`. I was able to generate a `.apk` file using `expo build:android` and then selecting the `'apk'` option. I could then download that .apk file on to real android devices to test the app.

I want to do the same thing for iOS. When I ran expo build:ios I selected the 'simulator' option and I was able to download a .app file. When I tried to airdrop this to my iPhone I could either choose to open it in the App Store or else my files but neither worked - I'm pretty sure it needs to be a `.ipa` file for it to be sideloaded.

I tried choosing the `'archive'` option but it was asking for an Apple Developer login - which I don't have.

As this is only a final year university project, I do not want to enroll as an Apple Developer or anything like that - I just simply want to generate an `.ipa` file from expo so I can send it to my friends to test on their phones to get feedback.

Thanks in advance.

---

Answer (score 3):

1. Generate .ipa file by running expo build:ios
2. Download .ipa file from your expo account projects.
3. Upload downloaded .ipa file to [Diawi](https://www.diawi.com).
4. Send the link to testers e.i. yourself

**Note**

**The client device or tester device UUID should be added in trusted device or device list on Apple appstore only then they will able to install the application.**

Comment: Whenever I download the iOS build from Expo it comes in a .tar.gz folder and when I unzip that, it extracts as a .app file. I can't find a .ipa anywhere.

I tried to upload the .app file to Diawi and I got this error - "4001009: Invalid .ipa file: missing embedded mobileprovision"

Comment: The app file is for the simulator. You can start the simulator and drag'n'drop the app file in it so it will install your app